# MySQL regex replace?

Tags: php, mysql, replace, phpmyadmin

I've got a table with blob text fields. This blob has a lot of html in it. One of the pieces of html is an h2. I would like to find all instances of a word in the h2 tag, and replace it with another word (while leaving other words the same).

For example, I would like to replace the h2 "wiggles" with "bumbles" in the following:

Before:

```
<h2>This is some wiggles html!</h2>
<p>And here is some more wiggles html that could be ignored</p>
<h2>And this is a decoy h2</h2>
```

After:

```
<h2>This is some bumbles html!</h2>
<p>And here is some more wiggles html that could be ignored</p>
<h2>And this is a decoy h2</h2>
```

A pitfall I'm concerned about is the regex not stopping at the end of the first h2, and rather continuing through to the last closing of it.

I have access to shell and phpmyadmin.

Comment: Is it wrong to want to +1 just for bumbles and wiggles?

Comment: Haha, I won't complain :). Gotta keep things fun ;)

Answer (score 3):

### Replacing text in MySQL with Regular Expressions

You can add a library to MySQL to gain this feature.

Adding: LIB_MYSQLUDF_PREG
Allows: Regular expression search & replace using PCRE.
Site: http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/

#### Examples:

```
SELECT PREG_REPLACE('/(.*?)(fox)/' , 'dog' , 'the quick brown fox' );
```

#### Yields:

```
the quick brown
```

### Matching HTML with Regular Expressions

Parsing HTML with regexp is not easy and has a lot of pitfalls. However, your example is simple enough that you should be able to do what your looking to do.

I think this will be helpful: http://haacked.com/archive/2004/10/25/usingregularexpressionstomatchhtml.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is no regexp replace feature in mySQL proper: The [regex functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) are match only.

There seems to be a [user defined function](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,54128,241263#msg-241263) that adds the functionality somehow, but it requires re-compiling mySQL and is probably not an option.

I'd recommend doing this using a programming/scripting language like PHP, using its built-in regex replace functions to change the content, and update the records.

**Edit:** overlooked the `php` tag.

Comment: Yeah, Oracle & PostgreSQL are the only db's I know with native regex replace functionality.  SQL Server 2005+, you have to build it yourself via CLR functions...

Answer (score 1):

Html is not a regular language therefore trying to parse it with regex is not the best option. In my opinion i would want to leverage a html parser to do this job. [Here is a sample parser.](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)

Enjoy!